# Backporting a package from an unreleased release?

Tags: package-management, release-management, backport

If I attempt to backport a package using a command similar to the following:

```
backportpackage -s xenial -d vivid ...
```

I end up with an error:

```
backportpackage: Error: Unknown release codename xenial
```

Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) has been announced but not released yet. How can I backport packages from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of valid releases accepted by `backportpackage` is stored in `/usr/share/distro-info/ubuntu.csv` (from the package [distro-info-data [image: Install distro-info-data]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/distro-info-data)).

To add a release, open the file and add a line to the bottom like this:

```
...
15.10,Wily Werewolf,wily,2015-04-23,2015-10-29,2016-07-29
16.04 LTS,Xenial Xerus,xenial,2015-10-22,2016-04-21,2021-04-21
```

`backportpackage` should now accept the release.